# Поиск по маске в mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

В БД есть записи типа `4646546515-56465654`
Нужно сделать поиск этих записей из БД по маске цифры-цифры

В regexp это было бы что-то вроде [0-9]+?-[0-9]+? , а как в sql прописать не понимаю.

Не могу подобрать выражение.

Comment: А в чем именно проблема? Как пробовали искать? На чем конкретно застряли?

Comment: @newman в regexp это было бы что-то вроде [0-9]+?-[0-9]+? , а как в sql прописать не понимаю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В MySQL есть оператор REGEXP

Оператор SQL будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '[0-9]+?-[0-9]+?';
```

Подробнее: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: по скорости кончено regexp трактор но большое спасибо!!!

Comment: @Sasha если вопрос в скорости, то надо думать и вносить изменения в структуру таблицы. Для конкретной задачи можно добавить поле типа TINYINT() и при любой модификации текстового поля определять в нем наличие этой подстроки и по факту ставить 1 или 0 в дополнительное поле. Немного усложняет вставку и редактирование, но зато поиск будет летать :)